# Data fetching from SugarCRM custom build module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I have a custom made module in SugarCRM called AOS_Products. I have stored a product detail in that module. I want to fetch that product detail using PHP.

Can anyone suggest how I can do that?

Comment: i hope you people are not getting the idea, so please help me out with the use of sugarcrm??? how can i customize with my business model as in how can i get data from the sugarcrm

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access sugarcrm's database, one module will be mapped to one database table.

But sugar will suggest you to use their SOAP/REST to access data in sugarcrm. Here is their [sugarcrm web service API document](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarEnterprise/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9000397).